# Images uploaded to SharePoint Document Library show black box with white 'X'

Tags: jpg

I have a document library where the user uploaded images to it and in the preview, they are showing as black box with white 'x'.  When launched, it continues to open with a box and 'x'.  If downloaded, the image opens up correctly.  I've changed the 'Default open behavior' to 'Open in the client application' as recommended in another site but no success.  When moved to another doc library, the image is ok.  The users need to keep the images within the document library and so creating a photo library is not an option.  This is a SP2013 environment.  Thanks.

Comment: Does the library require document approval?

Comment: I've seen a similar problem once, where the .jpg files were actually .png files (or the other way arround). As the file extension did not match the actual content, IE refuses to display the image.

Comment: No, the only option enabled is 'Check-out'.

Comment: Are your users checking in the image after uploading it?

When Check-in/check-out is enabled, all uploaded files are checked out by default.

Comment: Yes, the files are checked in as I can see them with me logged in and I don't see the checked out icon next to the file name.